# Hecke convergence factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

I was reading a paper [here](http://library.msri.org/nonmsri/cohen/cohenLimoges81.pdf). There the author define an infinite series

$$\sum_{ad-cb=1}(cz+d)^{-(k-j)}(az+b)^{-j}$$

where $k$ is an even integer bigger than 2 and $2\leqslant j\leqslant k-2$. Then this series is a cusp form. This series represents the $(j-1)$th period linear map of cusp forms. It still make sense for 0th and $(k-2)$th period, but the series defined in this way not converge. Then the author said we should introduce a **Hecke convergence factor**. But I could not find too much about what this thing is. Does anyone know anything about it? How will it help to define the series?